# On the Radially Decreasing Functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

We say that a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is radially decreasing if
\begin{align*}
\phi(x)=\phi_{0}(|x|)
\end{align*}
for a decreasing $\phi_{0}:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Is it possible to look for a radially decreasing $\phi\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that the derivatives $\partial^{\alpha}\phi$ are still radially decreasing up to certain $|\alpha|\leq N$?

If we try $f(x)=e^{-|x|^{2}}$, then this fails because $\partial_{1}f(x)=-2x_{1}e^{-|x|^{2}}$ which is not decreasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\phi$ and any first order derivative $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_k}$ are both radially decreasing (or just radially symmetric) then $\phi$ is necessarily constant.

*Proof:* For all $x \in \Bbb R^n$ is
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_k}(x) = -\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_k}(-x) = - \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_k}(x)
$$
where the first equality comes from the radial symmetry of $\phi$ (and the chain rule), and the second inequality comes from the radial symmetry of $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_k}$.

It follows that $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_k}$ is identically zero. Then
$$
\phi_0(t) = \phi(t \mathbf{e_k}) = \phi(0)
$$
for all $t \ge 0$ where $\mathbf{e_k}$ is the $k$-th unit vector. This proves that $\phi_0$ (and consequnently, $\phi$), is constant.

Comment: If $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, then what does $\phi'(x)$ mean?

Comment: @JohnBarber: What I meant is to consider the restricted map $x \mapsto \phi(x, 0, \ldots, 0)$ and its derivative. I will try to make that more clear ...

Comment: So $\phi$ isn't actually $\phi$ but its a restriction of $\phi$ ... ? Nonetheless, nice proof.

Comment: @JohnBarber, Dionel:: Is it clearer now?